# SWIFTUI Slider change thumb image or thumb size?

Tags: swift, xcode

How do I change the thumb size of a swift uiSlider

```
            HStack(spacing: 15){
                
                Image(systemName: "speaker.fill")
                
                Slider(value: $volume)
                
                Image(systemName: "speaker.wave.2.fill")
            }
```